# Pandas Rename one column Values when not equal to multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I am new to coding and Pandas any help would be much appreciated.
I have a column I wish to rename values Locations A-00-UD, A-01-UD, A-02-UD would = Audit, T-00-UD , T-02-UD, T-03-UD would = Transit and all other values would = stock. The problem I have is naming all the other values as Stock as in the full data-frame column is 15,000 lines long and has hundreds of different locations I wish to name stock.

Location

A-00-UD

A-01-UD

A-02-UD

A-03-UD

T-00-UD

T-01-UD

T-02-UD

T-03-UD

A-45-TR

S-30-RT

D-20-ED

V-00-LM

Comment: It's not that clear what the renaming should be like... What did you try already and why didn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) with [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) for exact match:

```
m1 = df['Location'].isin(['A-00-UD', 'A-01-UD', 'A-02-UD'])
m2 = df['Location'].isin(['T-00-UD', 'T-02-UD', 'T-03-UD'])
```

Or with [`startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) for check first value:

```
m1 = df['Location'].str.startswith('A')
m2 = df['Location'].str.startswith('T')

df['new'] = np.select([m1, m2], ['Audit', 'Transit'], default='Stock')
print (df)
   Location      new
0   A-00-UD    Audit
1   A-01-UD    Audit
2   A-02-UD    Audit
3   A-03-UD    Audit
4   T-00-UD  Transit
5   T-01-UD  Transit
6   T-02-UD  Transit
7   T-03-UD  Transit
8   A-45-TR    Audit
9   S-30-RT    Stock
10  D-20-ED    Stock
11  V-00-LM    Stock
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dictionary to map the first character of `Location`:

```
mapper = {'A': 'Audit', 'T': 'Transit'}

df['Location'] = df['Location'].str[0].map(mapper).fillna('Stock')
```

Alternatively, using [`numpy.select`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), you can specify conditions, values for each condition and a default value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Location': ['A-00-UD', 'T-01-UD', 'S-30-RT']})

conditions = [df['Location'].str[0] == 'A', df['Location'].str[0] == 'T']
values = ['Audit', 'Transit']

df['Location'] = np.select(conditions, values, 'Stock')

print(df)

  Location
0    Audit
1  Transit
2    Stock
```